# Django, не могу создать связь ManyToMany

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

В django создал две модели, между которыми установил связь ManyToMany. Вот код моделей:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        book_info = ('Название книги: ' + str(self.title) + ', цена: ' + str(self.price))
        return book_info


class Guests(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    age = models.IntegerField(default=20)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    book = models.ManyToManyField(Book, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        guest_info = ('Фамилия: ' + str(self.last_name) + ', Имя: ' + str(self.first_name) + ', Возраст: ' + str(self.age) + ', владеет машиной: ' + str(self.car) + ', автор книги: ' + str(self.book))
        return guest_info
```

Вот код admin.py:

```
class GuestsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # list_display = ('last_name', 'first_name', 'birth_date', 'age', 'sex', 'is_working')
    list_display = ('last_name', 'first_name', 'age', 'car')
    filter_horizontal = (['book'])


class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('pk', 'brand', 'model', 'color')


class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('pk', 'title', 'price')

admin.site.register(Guests, GuestsAdmin)
admin.site.register(Car, CarAdmin)
admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

При этом я не могу привязать ни один объект книг к объекту гостей. В админ панели при добавлении книг и сохранении появляется сообщение такого характера: "Фамилия: Fedorova, Имя: Mariya, Возраст: 34, владеет машиной: Brand: Kia, model: Rio, color: Red, автор книги: hello.Book.None” was changed successfully."[image: Внутри объекта гость это выглядит так:]

Код добавления вручную тоже не работает:

```
guest = Guests.objects.get(last_name='Fedorova')
book = Book.objects.get(title='Война и мир')
book.guests_set.add(guest)
```

По итогу, в графическом интерфейсе отображаются выбранные книги, но при выводе объекта в консоль выводится следующее: "Фамилия: Fedorova, Имя: Mariya, Возраст: 34, владеет машиной: Brand: Kia, model: Rio, color: Red, автор книги: hello.Book.None".
Прошу помощи в поиске ошибки. Буду рад любым предположениям и идеям, которые помогут мне понять в чем дело. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А попробуйтe без _set просто .add()

```
guest.book.add(book)
```

В модели Guests добавте метод:

```
       def get_book(self):
          return ",".join([str(p) for p in self.book.all()])
```

и в admin.py

```
 list_display = ('get_book')
```

В админке должно все заработать.

Comment: Так не сработает, необходимо именно через _set делать.

Comment: А с админкой как?

Comment: В админке в колонке "GET BOOK" книги появились. Но если получать объект через принт в консоли, то там по прежнему "hello.Book.None". Не очень понимаю, что за фишка такая. С чем это может быть связано? (hello - название приложения)

Comment: Εще раз, о каком принте идет речь?

Comment: Вывод объекта на печать в консоль pycharm.

Comment: а в админке новые объекты создаются?

Comment: Вот как это выглядит сейчас:
[https://download.ru/files/7lCZXUcg]
Т.е. книги вроде привязываются, но смогу ли я их выдернуть запросом к базе - буду сейчас пробовать.

Comment: Да, поиск гостя по названию книги работает.
Вот такой код:
`guest = Guests.objects.filter(book__title='Электромагнитная совместимость')`
Выводит в консоль следующее содержание:
<QuerySet [<Guests: Фамилия: Fedorova, Имя: Mariya, Возраст: 34, владеет машиной: Brand: Kia, model: Rio, color: Red, автор книги: hello.Book.None>]>
По сути, меня смущает в этом выводе только "автор книги: **hello.Book.None>**"

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался с ситуацией. В предложенном решении верно указан способ получения книг при связи ManyToMany. Т.е. если заменить

```
def __str__(self):
        guest_info = (... str(self.book))
        return guest_info
```

на

```
    def __str__(self):
        guest_info = (... str(self.get_book()))
        return guest_info
```

то, при обращении к объекту, все книги, связанные с ним отображаются нормально. Таким образом для связи ManyToMany необходимо реализовывать отображение перечня объектов через метод, а не просто в лоб.